# Problem with finding the highest exam range

Tags: java

I have an assignment that requires me to create a method called getExamRange that looks at an array which includes the exam scores of several students, takes the lowest and highest scores, and subtracts the minimum exam score from the maximum exam score. I also have to create a getMostImprovedStudent which run the getExamRange method on an array of Students and returns the student with the highest exam range. I'm having trouble getting the correct results when the code is run. What is causing this problem?

Here is the code for the Student.java class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Student
{
    private static final int NUM_EXAMS = 4;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int gradeLevel;
    private double gpa;

    private int[] exams;
    private int numExamsTaken;

    /**
     * This is a constructor.  A constructor is a method
     * that creates an object -- it creates an instance
     * of the class. What that means is it takes the input
     * parameters and sets the instance variables (or fields)
     * to the proper values.
     * 
     * Check out StudentTester.java for an example of how to use
     * this constructor. 
     */
    public Student(String fName, String lName, int grade)
    {
        firstName = fName;
        lastName = lName;
        gradeLevel = grade;
        exams = new int[NUM_EXAMS];
        numExamsTaken = 0;
    }

    public int getExamRange()
    {
        Arrays.sort(exams);
        int examScore1 = exams[0];
        int examScore2 = 0;
        int lastPos = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < exams.length - 1; i++)
        {
            lastPos++;
        }
        examScore2 = exams[lastPos];
        return examScore2 - examScore1;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    public void addExamScore(int score)
    {
        exams[numExamsTaken] = score;
        numExamsTaken++;
    }

    // This is a setter method to set the GPA for the Student.
    public void setGPA(double theGPA)
    {
        gpa = theGPA;
    }

    /**
     * This is a toString for the Student class. It returns a String
     * representation of the object, which includes the fields
     * in that object.
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName + " is in grade: " + gradeLevel;
    }
}
```

and here is the code for the Classroom.java class:

```
public class Classroom
{
    Student[] students;
    int numStudentsAdded;


    public Classroom(int numStudents)
    {
        students = new Student[numStudents];
        numStudentsAdded = 0;
    }

    public Student getMostImprovedStudent()
    {
        int highestScore = 0;
        int score = 0;
        int location = 0;
        int finalLocation = 0;
        for(Student s: students)
        {
            score = s.getExamRange();
            location++;
            if(score > highestScore)
            {
                highestScore = score;
                finalLocation = location;
            }
        }
        return students[finalLocation - 1];
    }

    public void addStudent(Student s)
    {
        students[numStudentsAdded] = s;
        numStudentsAdded++;
    }

    public void printStudents()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numStudentsAdded; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(students[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the directions for the assignment which state what the methods are supposed to do:

**Taking our Student and Classroom example from earlier, you should fill in the method getMostImprovedStudent, as well as the method getExamRange. The most improved student is the one with the largest exam score range.**

**To compute the exam score range, you must subtract the minimum exam score from the maximum exam score.**

**For example, if the exam scores were 90, 75, and 84, the range would be 90 - 75 = 15.**

Comment: What was your input? What was your output? What was your expected output? How are they different?

Comment: My school uses a system that automatically inputs values and creates the Student and Classroom objects, but it only shows the result with the expected output and actual output, without showing the input.

Comment: hey @pcgamer2315132 try below code I have written

Answer (score 0):

Firstly let us look at the getExamRange function

```
public int getExamRange(){
        if(exams == null ||exams.length == 0){
           return 0;
         }
        int min = exams[0];
        int max = exams[0];
        for (int i : exams
             ) {
            if(i<min){
                min=i;
            }
            if(i>max){
                max=i;
            }
        }
        return max - min;
    }
```

and now on getMostImprovedStudent

```
public Student getMostImprovedStudent()
    {
        if(students == null ||students[0] == null || students.length=0){
           return null;
        }
        int highestScore = students[0].getExamRange();
        int score = 0;
        Student mostImprovedStudent = students[0]
        for(int i=0;i<students.length;i++)
        {
            if(students[i]!=null){
               score = students[i].getExamRange();
            if(score > highestScore)
            {
                highestScore = score;
                mostImprovedStudent = students[i];
            }
          }

        }
        return mostImprovedStudent;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the exam range method displays the wrong value  one of the tests create a class with an incomplete Student array that shows an error "NullPointerException: You appear to be referencing a variable that is null"

Comment: It still outputs the same error :/ I'll edit my post to include the directions for the assignment, maybe that will help.

Comment: please try it now @pcgamer2315132

Comment: getMostImprovedStudent() now works correctly, but getExamRange() still doesn't work correctly

Comment: Never mind, it displays the correct result now, I just had to make some minor changes in the getExamRange() code, thank you.